# MATLAB regress function and Normalizing Data

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I am trying to perform a multiple linear regression in MATLAB using the `regress` function, and I am using a number of different variables that involve different scales and units. I am assume the answer to this question is yes, but should I normalize each variable before running the regression? I'm not sure if MATLAB does so automatically. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should. If you want to normalize it between 0 and 1, you could use mat2gray function (assuming "vector" as your list of variables).

```
norm_vect = mat2gray(vector);
```

This function is used to convert  matrix into an image, but works well if you don't want to write yours. You also can use a simple normalization like:

```
for i = 1:length(vector)
   norm_vect(i) = (vector(i)-min(vector))/(max(vector)-min(vector));
end
```